# Laravel + PhpStorm: is it possible set "Go to File" paste HomeController@index and direct jump to function?

Tags: laravel, phpstorm

When I use the Laravel Debugbar from the route tab, it show the file and the function. I usually copy the file name and the function.

[image: debugbar]

When I go to PhpStorm and then trigger the `Go to File`, I paste the file and function it always show not found. I have manually delete the `@`+function name, then manually scroll to the function.

[image]

Is there any way to jump to the file from Laravel debugbar or PhpStorm allow to do so?

Comment: 1) Try `ClassName#method` syntax instead, but on `Classes` tab and not `Files`. 2) PhpStorm does not understand Laravel-specific `@` syntax . Here is the ticket to allow using the more natural for PHP `::` symbol: [WI-39109](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-39109). Overall it's rather unlikely that the IDE (the core) will support this `@` syntax, unless Laravel-specific plugin can provide that.

Comment: Hi LazyOne ClassName#method is working in Classes,  I should find way to edit the debugbar. thanks